# How to connect to several Bitcoin nodes using Bitcoin

Tags: development, nodes, library

I'm looking for a way to connect to several Bitcoin nodes using [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)...
I've been looking in different Bitcoin-for-Python libraries, but I haven't found anything :(
What should I do?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but check this out https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fallback_Nodes - some sub functionality in there will do what you require.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to communicate with several nodes, you can use existing JSON RPC libraries and issue requests via the API. Check out these libraries:

- [JSON-RPC](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/python-json-rpc)
- [python-jsonrpc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-jsonrpc)